# Json - recursively validate schema with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonschema

I'm trying to recursively validate a custom JSON schema against a template JSON Schema using the `jsonschema` module in Python 3.

The custom JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "endpoint": "rfc",
  "filter_by": ["change_ref", "change_i"],
  "expression": [
    {
      "field": "first_name",
      "operator": "EQ",
      "value": "O'Neil"
    },
    "AND",
    [
      {
        "field": "last_name",
        "operator": "NEQ",
        "value": "Smith"
      },
      "OR",
      {
        "field": "middle_name",
        "operator": "EQ",
        "value": "Sam"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "limit_results_to": "2"
}
```

The above can be generalized further by adding multiple `AND`s and `OR`s => my question related to recursivity.

The template that I'm trying to validate this schema against of is in the following piece of code:

```
import json
import jsonschema


def get_data(file):
    with open(file) as data_file:
        return json.load(data_file)


def json_schema_is_valid():
    data = get_data("other.json")
    valid_schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["endpoint", "filter_by", "expression", "limit_results_to"],
        "properties": {
            "endpoint": {
                "type": "string",
                "additionalProperties": False
            },
            "filter_by": {
                "type": ["string", "array"],
                "additionalProperties": False
            },
            "limit_results_to": {
                "type": "string",
                "additionalProperties": False
            },
            "expression": {
                "type": "array",
                "properties": {
                    "field": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "additionalProperties": False
                    },
                    "operator": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "additionalProperties": False
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "additionalProperties": False
                    }
                },
                "required": ["field", "operator", "value"]
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonschema.validate(data, valid_schema)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(json_schema_is_valid())
```

Now, something seems wrong because when I run the above code, I get `None` which might (not) be okay. When I'm trying to modify the `type` of a `property` in something that isn't allowed, I don't get any excception. Is there something wrong in my template? [Here](http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/?schema=N4IgLgngDgpiBcID2AjAVjAxmEAaEATjAI4CuAlkQCYIDaIMAdlVEuYzvgGbkA2YMAgH0UEPAwAeUIgGcZ5JI3G9yAW3Jghs0vxlCwSEAF180pLAJhyMGQlBMWbDnfDQ4iGWALsA5uICGVFQaCoz+vAAKBOaCVjYIXOEyMAC+3HwCwqIukLB0IJ7ejH74/gQE/mImIIHBVorhUTGW1rbwibzJaSAq6prauvqG8KC57gVevgFBIQ2R0RZxbR1d+DBSsvKKOW4INeWV4maLrS48MLw0I655HpPFIN3N/gYEO7cTRX7dAG7hpO5Rrs7l9Ht0iGRKDArvRzpdxM9XuI/rwAcYUhigAAA&value=N4IgpgdgJgDg9gSwgFxALhCANCAZggG2TACcB9AIwE91McCEBbBZMksAZwFciOzk4tbOAAeMdhw4I4EdAG0AugF8gAA=&theme=bootstrap2&iconlib=fontawesome4&object_layout=normal&show_errors=interaction), it looks like the expression properties are not parsed. More, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752716/json-schema-recursive-schema-definition) that I can make my template to recursively validate my custom JSON schema using `'$ref': '#'` but I didn't quite understand how to use it. Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema looks to work, excluding the recursive part. Looking at the source code on GitHub for [`jsonschema.validate`](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/blob/master/jsonschema/validators.py#L492), we can see that the code doesn't have a `return`. And so I think it's safe to assume that the way you validate would be using something like:

```
try:
    jsonschema.validate(json_data, schema)
except ...:
    print('invalid json')
else:
    print('valid json')
```

---

To create your recursion you should make two definitions. I found out how to do this from [Recursive JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24989786). You just need to make a couple of definitions. First are your normal comparisons. This is pretty much just moving your current definition out into it's own definition.

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "comparison": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "field": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "operator": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": ["field", "operator", "value"]
        }
    }
}
```

To perform your recursive boolean comparisons is a little harder. I don't know how to limit arrays to three items, where the second is a different type so I opted to using an object, which has three well defined items. Also the first and last item should have the same type so that you can do comparisons like `(a and b) or (c and d)`. And so I got the following schema:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "comparison": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "field": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "operator": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": ["field", "operator", "value"]
        },
        "booleanComparison": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "item1": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {"$ref": "#/definitions/comparison"},
                        {"$ref": "#/definitions/booleanComparison"}
                    ]
                },
                "operator": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "item2": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {"$ref": "#/definitions/comparison"},
                        {"$ref": "#/definitions/booleanComparison"}
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": ["item1", "operator", "item2"]
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "endpoint": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "filter_by": {
            "type": ["string", "array"]
        },
        "limit_results_to": {
            "type": "string",
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "expression": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/comparison"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/booleanComparison"}
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": ["endpoint", "filter_by", "expression", "limit_results_to"]
}
```

Which says the following is valid:

```
{
    "endpoint": "rfc",
    "filter_by": ["change_ref", "change_i"],
    "limit_results_to": "2",
    "expression": {
        "item1": {
            "field": "first_name",
            "operator": "EQ",
            "value": "O'Neil"
        },
        "operator": "AND",
        "item2": {
            "item1": {
                "field": "last_name",
                "operator": "NEQ",
                "value": "Smith"
            },
            "operator": "OR",
            "item2": {
                "field": "middle_name",
                "operator": "EQ",
                "value": "Sam"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However says it's invalid if you change `"value": "Sam"` to `"value": true`, as it's the wrong type. So it seems to work as intended recursively.